# In C++17, why do associative containers have an `erase` member function that takes (non-`const`) `iterator`?

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap, c++17, const-iterator

See, *e.g.,* http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase

In C++03 there were three overloads:

```
void erase( iterator pos );
void erase( iterator first, iterator last );
size_type erase( const key_type& key );
```

In C++11, the first and second overloads were changed to take `const_iterator` so that they could be called with either `iterator` or `const_iterator`. The first overload was also improved by having it return the iterator to the element after the one erased:

```
iterator erase( const_iterator pos );
void erase( const_iterator first, const_iterator last );
size_type erase( const key_type& key );
```

In C++17, a non-const overload was re-introduced:

```
iterator erase( const_iterator pos );
iterator erase( iterator pos );
void erase( const_iterator first, const_iterator last );
size_type erase( const key_type& key );
```

Why is this needed? It was not added for the ranged `erase`, nor for `insert`, nor for any of the sequence containers such as `vector`, `deque`, and `list`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was done to address [LWG defect 2059](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2059). Consider the example from the link

```
#include <map>

struct X
{
  template<typename T>
  X(T&) {}
};

bool operator<(const X&, const X&) { return false; }

void erasor(std::map<X,int>& s, X x)
{
  std::map<X,int>::iterator it = s.find(x);
  if (it != s.end())
    s.erase(it);
}
```

The call to `map::erase` at the end is ambiguous because both `map::erase(const_iterator)` and `map::erase(key_type const&)` are equally good matches as they each require a user defined conversion.

Reintroducing the `map::erase(iterator)` overload fixes this problem.